# Cannot register a servlet which doesn't have mapping in web.xml by ServletRunner?

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, http-unit

I am using **com.meterware.servletunit.ServletRunner** to initialize one of my servlets. 
I try to use the next method:

```
ServletRunner.registerServlet(String resourceName, String servletClassName)
```

The resourceName, as I understand, is servlet mapping, say "/myservlet/*" or so.

But the problem is this servlet has no mapping in web.xml file and is supposed to be initialized on startup. I need to initialize this servlet in my JUnit. How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to alert Russell Gold of your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do the following and it should work as expected
where HelloAppEngine is my servlet class

```
@Test
public void doGetWritesResponse() throws Exception {
    ServletRunner sr = new ServletRunner();
    sr.registerServlet("/hello", HelloAppEngine.class.getName());
    WebClient wc = sr.newClient();
    WebResponse response = wc.getResponse(http://localhost/hello");
    assertEquals("content type", "text/plain", response.getContentType());
    assertEquals("response text is ", "Hello app Engine", response.getText());
}
```

the source code for `HelloAppEngine` is as the following

```
    @WebServlet(name = "HelloAppEngine", value = "/hello")
    public class HelloAppEngine extends HttpServlet {    
    @Override
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
     response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().print("Hello app Engine");
     }
    }
```